# Best structure for LDAP server?

Tags: ldap, structure

I have to define a structure for one LDAP server and I doubt which strucuture is better. 
Let's say there are 100 members, the company has 3 deparments (ie: marketing, sales and engineering) and each person could be in more than one deparment.

First option:

```
dn=company, dc=com
ou=people
ou=deparment 
ou=rol (They can be staff, employee, temp, etc..)
```

Second option:

```
dn=company, dc=com
ou=marketing
ou=sales
ou=engineering
```

So, what do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't try to mirror your actual organization in the DIT. Organizations change, people occupy more than one role, customers become suppliers, ... Your first option is preferable.